# how to combine the result of one Mysql (sub)query that returns multiple rows and use that for another query

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have two tables, one that stores serial number **uut_build**, and another for measurements that belong to the serial numbers **measure_list**,  I'm trying to get the count of records in **measure_list** that belongs to a unique serial number.
Query #1

```
select id, uut_sn from uut_build where uut_sn like 'A%';
```

Query #2

```
select count(*) from measure_list as m WHERE m.uut_id = [result from query #1]
```

Is it possible to do this with just one query statement?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT ub.uut_sn,
          COALESCE(COUNT(ml.*), 0) AS cnt
     FROM UUT_BUILD ub
LEFT JOIN MEASURE_LIST ml ON ml.uut_id = ub.uut_sn
    WHERE ub.uut_sn LIKE 'A%'
 GROUP BY ub.uut_sn
```

It's a little unclear what columns link the two tables...

This will return all serial numbers - if they don't have a record in `MEASURE_LIST`, the cnt value will be zero.  If you only want a list of records that have records in `MEASURE_LIST`, remove "LEFT" from the query I provided.

Comment: I suspect id on uut_build corresponds to uut_id on measure_list - otherwise, the desired output could be returned by querying measure_list only.

Comment: @Mark Bannister: Depends if the OP wants to get values from the `UUT_BUILD` table as well.  And running the query on only the `MEASURE_LIST` table will only show serials that exist in the table - it would never show those who don't have supporting records in `MEASURE_LIST`.

Comment: Yes - I was more concerned with the linkage field.

Comment: Thanks for the input and sorry for being unclear.  The tables are related by the id field of uut_sn, which is part of the measrue_list.  The suggestion above gave me enough lead-way to get the query to work.  FYI, the final solution is:

SELECT ub.uut_sn, COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) AS cnt   FROM uut_build as ub LEFT JOIN measure_list as ml ON ml.uut_id = ub.id     WHERE
 ub.uut_sn LIKE 'A%'  GROUP BY ub.uut_sn;